# Using ImageMagick to change background of an animated gif into transparent, but frames overlapped. How to solve?

Tags: image, imagemagick, gif, transparent

I want to change the gif background into transparent, and I use the following command of ImageMagick:

> > convert input.gif -transparent white output.gif

However, the  output has ghosting effect, the later frames overlapped with its previous frames.

//Sorry, I don't have enouth reputation to post my own images. 
A example is here: http://tieba.baidu.com/p/1090763568

How can I make them do not overlap? Or in other words, no ghosting effect?

Comment: Try adding `-set dispose background` immediately after the input image name.

Answer (score 2):

I think the *"answer"* is that it is a badly made animation for your purposes. You can see that the animation consists of 12 frames like this with ImageMagick:

```
identify anim.gif

anim.gif[0] GIF 400x350 400x350+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anim.gif[1] GIF 1x1 400x350+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anim.gif[2] GIF 226x152 400x350+85+8 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anim.gif[3] GIF 218x152 400x350+89+8 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anim.gif[4] GIF 210x152 400x350+93+8 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anim.gif[5] GIF 202x152 400x350+97+8 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anim.gif[6] GIF 194x152 400x350+101+8 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anim.gif[7] GIF 194x152 400x350+101+8 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anim.gif[8] GIF 202x152 400x350+97+8 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anim.gif[9] GIF 210x152 400x350+93+8 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anim.gif[10] GIF 218x152 400x350+89+8 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anim.gif[11] GIF 226x152 400x350+85+8 8-bit sRGB 256c 106KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

You can split the image into its constituent frames and make the white areas  transparent like this:

```
convert anim.gif -transparent none frame-%02d.gif

-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      9777  4 May 11:11 frame-11.gif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      9732  4 May 11:11 frame-10.gif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      9681  4 May 11:11 frame-09.gif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      9835  4 May 11:11 frame-08.gif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      9533  4 May 11:11 frame-07.gif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      9479  4 May 11:11 frame-06.gif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      9986  4 May 11:11 frame-05.gif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff      9907  4 May 11:11 frame-04.gif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     10070  4 May 11:11 frame-03.gif
-rw-r--r--@  1 mark  staff     10099  4 May 11:11 frame-02.gif
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff        43  4 May 11:11 frame-01.gif
-rw-r--r--@  1 mark  staff     15917  4 May 11:11 frame-00.gif
```

You can also montage all the frames together like this:

```
convert anim.gif -transparent white miff:- | montage -tile 3x -frame 5 - montage.jpg
```

[image]

If you try to put the frames back together with a disposal method of `background`, you will lose the word `welcome` which only appears in the first frame:

```
convert -dispose background frame-0* a.gif
```

[image]

If you try and composite the first frame (so you have "welcome") with each of the others before animating them, you will get a black ghost because the boy and girl characters also appear in the first frame:

```
convert frame-00.gif frame-02.gif -geometry +85+8 -composite x.gif
```

[image]

The only solution I see is to take the first frame into Photoshop and remove the boy and girl, then rebuild the animation... but then again, I am no expert in animation and now that all the frames are *"on the table"*, someone else may be able to tell you an easier method.

Comment: To use transparent and reset between each image use:
`magick convert anim.gif -transparent none frame-%02d.png`
`magick convert -dispose background frame-*.png output.gif`

Answer (score 1):

If you edit it with Gimp, there's an option to change the disposal method to replace ("Frame disposal where unspecified: One frame per layer (replace)", so that each frame is rendered after fully clearing the previous one).

However, if you don't want to edit each file, one at a time, using another program, I've created a ruby script to fix this for me (batch fix is possible if you need it).
The only way I've found is to do a binary replacement of the disposal methods used by ImageMagick to the value of the method used by Gimp ("Replace", 9: the only one that works on animated gifs with transparent background as far as I know). Note: to run the script you would have to install ruby (if you don't have it) and edit the file names you wish to work upon.

[Ruby script to change gif's disposal method to "replace"](https://github.com/LukeMS/Gif_replace_disposal_method).

[Script's description (with a description of the problem and sample animations, overlapping (buggy) and replacing (working)](https://github.com/LukeMS/Gif_replace_disposal_method/wiki).