# wand: How to assemble transparent gif / clear background each frame

Tags: python, image, imagemagick, gif, wand

So I have a series of transparent pngs and append them to a new Image()

```
with Image() as new_gif:
    for img_path in input_images:
        with Image(filename=img_path) as inimg:
            # create temp image with transparent background to composite
            with Image(width=inimg.width, height=inimg.height, background=None) as new_img:
                new_img.composite(inimg, 0, 0)
                new_gif.sequence.append(new_img)
    new_gif.save(filename=output_path)
```

unfortunately the background is not "cleared" when the new image is appended. They'll have the last image there as well:

[image]

But how do I clear the background? I though I do exactly that by compositing into a new image upfront.. `:| HALP!!

I see there is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275123/using-imagemagick-to-change-background-of-an-animated-gif-into-transparent-but) thing with commandline ImageMagick but wand doesn't have anything like that. So far I have to workaround with a fitting background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the source images, I can assume the `-set dispose background` is what's needed. For [wand](/questions/tagged/wand), you'll need to call `wand.api.library.MagickSetOption` method.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

with Image() as new_gif:
    # Tell new gif how to manage background
    library.MagickSetOption(new_gif.wand, 'dispose', 'background')
    for img_path in input_images:
        library.MagickReadImage(new_gif.wand, img_path)
    new_gif.save(filename=output_path)
```

[image: Assembled transparent GIF]

*Or alternatively...*

You can extent wand to manage Background Dispose behavior. This approach would give you the benefit of alter/generate each frame programmatically. But the down side would include a lot more work with [ctypes](/questions/tagged/ctypes). For example.

```py
import ctypes
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

# Tell python about library method
library.MagickSetImageDispose.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, # Wand
                                          ctypes.c_int]    # DisposeType
# Define enum DisposeType
BackgroundDispose = ctypes.c_int(2)
with Image() as new_gif:
    for img_path in input_images:
        with Image(filename=img_path) as inimg:
            # create temp image with transparent background to composite
            with Image(width=inimg.width, height=inimg.height, background=None) as new_img:
                new_img.composite(inimg, 0, 0)
                library.MagickSetImageDispose(new_img.wand, BackgroundDispose)
                new_gif.sequence.append(new_img)
    # Also rebuild loop and delay as ``new_gif`` never had this defined.
    new_gif.save(filename=output_path)
```

[image: With MagickSetImageDispose] <- still needs delay correction

Comment: Hmm doesn't work. I think I deleted the original images :/ But If you view the image I posted ^ via `xnview` for example you can step through the single images **Shift+PgDown/PgUp** and see that they are actually stored without the trail!! I first thought it's about how they are put together not how they are rendered ...

Comment: Of course it all works with commandline imageMagick and `-dispose background`. oh darn. I wanted it to be nice and pythonic... :|

Comment: Ah! I get it. We'll need to build the animation directly through the C-API

Comment: The alternative works! But weird that you set it for each image if the dispose thing is an attibute for rendering the animated gif? Or it isnt? I'm already setting the delay too. But I do it after it was attached to the sequence by getting last image, setting delay and calling destroy() dunno if there is a better way.

Comment: Did you get a definitive solution to your problem? How did you end up writing your code?

Comment: I ended up using @emcconville ‘s ctypes solution and it worked for me. I don’t understand what it’s doing but it works.